# Grails: handling HTTP-session timeout event

Tags: grails, session-timeout, http-status-code-401, url-mapping

I'm writing Grails application which uses Sprint Security for authentication. I need to display a message to a user, who has been automatically logged off due to inactivity.

My application uses both AJAX requests and direct requests to the controllers. I noticed, that for AJAX requests Sprint Security returns HTTP response with code 401, and I have redefined default URL mapping in such a way:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
         // ...

         "401" (controller: 'errors', action: 'inactivityLogout')
    }
}
```

And here is the body of `inacticityLogout()` method:

```
def inactivityLogout() {
    log.debug("the user is logged out due to inactivity")
    session.setAttribute('inactivityMessage', "You have been logged out due to inactivity.")
    render(status: 401)
}
```

Then the `LoginController` checks if `inactivityMessage` attribute is set, and displays corresponding message on Login page.

The problem is that this solution works fine for AJAX calls, but doesn't work when I'm trying to navigate to another page just by clicking direct link in the application. In second case log is empty, so the method `inactivityLogout` is not called.

Firebug shows that application returns code 302 Moved Temporarily, so I though that this is a reason. But then I noticed that the same code is returned for AJAX calls as well. So, now I have no ideas what is the difference between the AJAX and non-AJAX requests and why the last are not handled by Grails URL mapping engine.

Any ideas, what could be wrong with my current solution? Can this problem be solved in completely different way?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to show the message based on them clicking something or automatically when the session expires, without any user interaction at all?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to show the message without any user interaction. Just want to let the user know why he was logged off the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, this is what I do:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   statusCode: {
     401: function () {
       $('#ajaxAuthModal').modal('show');
     }
   }
});
```

I have that in a global JS file so that all my ajax requests handle a 401.  Then I just show a modal that tells the user they need to login again.  The only real difference you would need to achieve what you want is to poll a secure resource via ajax. This would allow the 401 function to trigger when the 401 is returned.

Most JavaScript libraries like jQuery should have a similar feature to `$.ajaxSetup()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is great solution for AJAX requests! But I also need to redirect user to LoginController, when he tries to navigate to another, and display message there. Spring Security redirects user to LoginController automatically when session expires, but then I need to understand, whether users just came to this page by direct link to the website, or he was logged off because of inactivity. May be I didn't state it clear enough, but the message should be shown not as pop-up, but like a plain text on login page.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, the idea is to show the message without any user interaction. Just want to let the user know why he was logged off the system.

So essentially once the user has loaded the page there is no contact with the server. The server can't "push" a message to the browser. So what you will have to do is check if there is an active session with JavaScript. You can do this with a timer pretty easily.

In your main.gsp set a javascript variable to `${session.maxInactiveInterval}`. This will give you the maximum length of the users session. Simply start a `setTimeout( function() { /* code to display to the user here */ }, maxInterval)`.

Remember to reset the interval on AJAX calls, because since the page isn't being reloaded, it won't get reset.

As a side note, the URL mappings should only come into play on non-AJAX requests because the page isn't being reloaded, thus nothing to display the page to. You will have to use something like @Gregg is using to handle AJAX requests.